# Apache VirtualHost returns Access Forbiddon error 403

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have a Windows dev server running Apache/PHP/MySQL

I am trying to add a new VirtualHost entry.  I have a VirtualHost entry already which works for wildcard .dev domains for folders in a directory under the dev servers Drive E

The dev server is located on a Drive letter `E` and the virtualhost entry I am having trouble with is on a different drive letter `F`.  below is my config and error log

### Apache virtualhost entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "F:\My Documents\E-Books"
    ServerName ebooks.dev
    ErrorLog "F:\My Documents\E-Books\error-log.log"
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

---

### Error Log Entry:

```
[Mon May 08 20:34:20.070003 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 15668:tid 1628] [client 127.0.0.1:50373] AH01630: 
client denied by server configuration: F:/My Documents/E-Books/favicon.ico, referer: http://ebooks.dev/
```

---

### Problem

Could the problem be that the new virtualhost entry is pointing to a different drive letter?  I had trouble before trying to make a symlink from a folder on 2 different drive letters so maybe apache doesnt work either on different drives ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a "Directory" Entry for

```
F:\My Documents\E-Books
```

with a `Require all granted`

Having it as documentroot does not automatically give access